# Periodic automorphism of $S^{3}$ and fixed point set

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: S^{3} \rightarrow S^{3} $ be a periodic orientation preserving homeomorphism of order $p$. Suppose there exist two circles $S^{1} $, $A$ and $B$ such that $f(A ) = A $ and $f(B ) = B$. Then is it the case that $A = B$ and $A$ is a fixed point set?

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. Think of $S^3$ as the set of quaternions of norm $1$, i.e. all $x+yi+zj+tk$ with $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1$. Then let $f$ be multiplication on the left by $i$, and let $A$ be the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, $z=t=0$, and $B$ be the circle $z^2+t^2=1$, $x=y=0$. If you were thinking of $p$ as a prime number, then replace my $f$ by multiplication on the left by $\cos(2\pi/p)+i\sin(2\pi/p)$.